# Div into center of screen using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to using flex.
My problem is to design a site page. I want to put a div tag in the center of the web page using flex.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. We suppose you make some research before asking her, if you serach on SO you will find a lot of answer about centering elements with flexbox

Answer (score -1):

To fix this add to the parent element `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;`

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.centered{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered">
        This is in the center
    </div>
</div>
```